# NSPredicate query for not containing a specific string

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

Looked high and low for this one but can't find my answer. I am looking to query core data for all records which are NOT equal to a specified string. For example, all records which are not equal to the current session ID. I have tried these to no avail:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"listingID != %@", [sitListingID objectAtIndex:i]];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ NOT CONTAINS[cd] %@",@"listingID", [sitListingID objectAtIndex:i]];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ NOT CONTAINS %@",@"listingID", [sitListingID objectAtIndex:i]];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"listingID NOT like %@", [sitListingID objectAtIndex:i]];
```

Nothing works.HEEEEELP!!!
----------------------------------------------------- more code

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ListingRecord" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"sessionID <> %@", uniqueSessionListings];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: could you provide a whole method? May be you fetch emtpy data.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Your first predicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"listingID != %@", sessionID];
```

should work to find all records where the attribute `listingID` is not equal to `sessionID` (provided that `listingID` and `sessionID` have the same type).

If both are strings and you want to find all records where `listingID` *does not contain* the string `sessionID` as a substring, then this predicate should work:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (listingID CONTAINS %@)", sessionID];
```

Use "CONTAINS[cd]" if the string comparison should be done case and diacritical insensitive.

*NOTE*: You can specify the attribute name as an argument, but then you must use `%K` instead of `%@` as format:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (%K CONTAINS %@)", @"listingID", sessionID];
```

Comment: HECK YEAH! That did the trick. Quick side question, unless I am going blind I did not read your solution in the Apple Predicate Programming Guide. Did I miss it in the guide or is this covered somewhere else? (asking for future reference)

Comment: @sangony: When I started with Core Data programming I had also difficulties with predicates, the Predicate Programming Guide could be more detailed. It is sometimes tricky to combine all the possible comparisons, operations and predicates in the right order. You could say that everything is said in the "BNF Definition of Cocoa Predicates" :-) - I learned a lot from reading other people's questions and answers here at SO.

Comment: This is helpful but is there a way to add a "does not contain" operator to an `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate`? There is a `NSContainsPredicateOperatorType` but not a `NSDoesNotContainPredicateOperatorType` (unless I've missed it).

Comment: @Jon: I don't know. Normally I use `predicateWithFormat` and seldom build predicate programmatically. I assume that there is some way to *negate* an expression ...

Comment: @MartinR I solved this by using a custom `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate`. The custom class overrides the `templateViews` method and sets a custom popup to handle the "contains" and "does not contain" operators. Then, in the `setPredicate:` method, it **does not** set its (or super's) predicate. Instead, it parses the predicate format passed in and saves the operator & right-side expression to ivars. Then, in the `predicateWithSubpredicates:` method it creates a new predicate and, if it is "does not contain" operator, it returns the `NSCompoundPredicate notPredicateWithSubpredicate` predicate.

Comment: @MartinR are the brackets around "%k CONTAINS %@" required/needed?

Comment: @pnizzle: Probably not, but I did not test it.

Comment: Super tip about %K that is easy to forget

Comment: @MartinR how to perform same kind of task in swift 3.0

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya: `let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "...", ...)` – the format string is the same as in Objective-C.

Comment: thank you for replay but now I got answer if you don't mind then I just edit in your answer